# Run Kali without installing on machine

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb

I have a LiveUSB of Linux Kali-mini, I am able to boot it up but how do I run it without installing it to my machine (like I am able to do on lubuntu), I can't find an option for it.

The only options available to me are:
-Install
-Advanced options >
-Help
-Install with speech synthesis

Comment: When it boots up, there should be an option for "Digital Forensics" or something like that... I believe that lets you use it without installing it to the machine...

Comment: @Interesting... Afraid I don't have that option, just to install with or without voice  synthesiser

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: Kali-linux-1.1.0a-i 386-mini

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, are you sure the ISO that you have is a live one?

Check [here](http://docs.kali.org/category/downloading) once.

Comment: I didn't realise I had to download a specific live version, I just downloaded the ISO from the download page

Comment: Kali mini simply doesn't have the options in the boot menu that the full version does, I'll have to download the full version (which will take about 15 hours)